# How do I stop IdentityServer4 refresh tokens expiring?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have implemented IdentityServer4 for an Amazon Alexa use case and seem to be having problems with refresh_tokens expiring:

My client is setup as follows:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = AlexaUsername,
    ClientName = "Amazon Alexa",
    ClientUri = "https://alexa.amazon.co.uk",
    LogoUri = "/images/alexa.png",
    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    // secret for authentication
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret(...)
    },
    RedirectUris =  Options.AlexaService.PermittedUris,
    // scopes that client has access to
    AllowedScopes = { IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, AlexaApiScope },
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
    AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 360,
    AllowRememberConsent = true
}
```

My Services are defined as follows (not cert is not null):

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config =>
{
    //config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=aspnetcore2x%2Csql-server
    config.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 7; 
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Add application services.
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateIssuer(settings);
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

var nestedServices = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var DataSecurityService = nestedServices.GetService<IDataSecurityService>();

if (cert == null)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(DataSecurityService))
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
}
else
{
    services.AddIdentityServer(options => { options.IssuerUri = settings.Authority;
                                           options.PublicOrigin = settings.Authority;
        })
    .AddSigningCredential(cert)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
    //.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
    })
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
}
```

I see this in the logs:

```
2018-08-04 09:24:40.091 +01:00 [DBG] Start token request validation
2018-08-04 09:24:40.098 +01:00 [DBG] Start validation of refresh token request
2018-08-04 09:24:40.119 +01:00 [DBG] eny2fizHyrW3t98T2oOqNN+wy8thQvUsNz3HDL8UhjU= found in database: false
2018-08-04 09:24:40.119 +01:00 [DBG] refresh_token grant with value: f9f345127502ac6b72598404ff9be5bba041224393f5332c7262acfa7f6157c5 not found in store.
2018-08-04 09:24:40.119 +01:00 [ERR] Invalid refresh token
2018-08-04 09:24:40.120 +01:00 [ERR] Refresh token validation failed. aborting.
2018-08-04 09:24:40.164 +01:00 [ERR] {
  "ClientId": "xxx",
  "ClientName": "Amazon Alexa",
  "GrantType": "refresh_token",
  "Raw": {
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": "xxx",
    "client_id": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

One thought I have had is that the refresh tokens are being rendered invalid with the IIS server restarts and not persisted. What do I need to change to get permanently valid refresh tokens that Alexa requires?

Comment: You set `AccessTokenLifetime` to 0. Why?

Comment: don't think I have! AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
I set AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime to 0 per http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: i wrote it accidentally, i wanted to write `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime`.

Comment: thank you. Per the documentation for `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime` **Zero** allows refresh tokens that never expire when used with `RefreshTokenExpiration = Sliding`

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2060

Comment: ok - interesting. I am using IdentityServer 2.2 on AspNetCore 2.1.2 though so should ostensibly be fixed! Will have a look at the override class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse` seems to have resolved things as well as copying the code in from the link above (I haven't yet proven if that code is necessary or not)